# websocket under load balance environment

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, websocket

I have few questions about the websocket and apache balancer

scenario as below

```
192.168.56.101  load balancer using apache 2.4
192.168.56.102  server A using tomcat 7.0.42 
192.168.56.103  server B using tomcat 7.0.42
```

apache load balancer configueration in http-vhost.conf as below

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
BalancerMember ajp://192.168.56.102:8009 route=jvm102
BalancerMember ajp://192.168.56.103:8009 route=jvm103
ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests stickysession=JSESSIONID nofailover=off
SetHandler balancer-manager
</Proxy> 
ProxyPass /ws ws://192.168.56.101/test/WebSocket/Wsapp/WsChatServlet
```

I want to use websocket technique ,so I will establish websocket connection

```
"ws://192.168.56.101/ws"
```

the purpose is that the websocket connection request could be pass by apache load balancer
,rather than assign the server A or server B IP address directly

when I establish the connection

`"ws://192.168.56.101/ws"`

I hope it could translate the url path automatically by apache balancer as following

```
"ws://192.168.56.102/test/WebSocket/Wsapp/WsChatServlet"
```

or

```
"ws://192.168.56.103/test/WebSocket/Wsapp/WsChatServlet"
```

so far ,It has some problems

Does the Websocket work under the load balancer environment ?

there are else solutions for sort of cases ?

Comment: As far as I know, the Websocket specification does not support proxiing through an Application Gateway (like Apache is in this scenario), because HTTP is only used to perform a Websocket Handshake. After that the connection downgrades to a simple TCP Point-to-Point Connection between the Apache Webserver and the Web Browser. Since Apache is not an TCP Load Balancer, it is not able to redirect the TCP connection to your Tomcats. A possible solution could be a Transport Layer Loadbalancer, but I am not fully aware of this stuff

Comment: So should I select the HAproxy or kaazing websocket gateway to substitude the apache balancer?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't answer that, but I am also interested (at the moment we can't use websockets because of proxy issues, so I am also interested if there are already solutions to this)... a little googling brought me to this --> http://blog.exceliance.fr/2012/11/07/websockets-load-balancing-with-haproxy/ (looks promising)

Comment: I'm confident it can work by pure apache2.4  proxy in my past experience,but it can't work under the load balance environment